# How to import Chocolatey function, core and extension to PowerShell sessions?

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, powershell-module

I find many `Chocolatey` helper functions:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\functions
```

and extension functions

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-core
```

are very useful when you develop even non `Chocolatey` packages. Is there any way to import these function to `Powershell` scripts and `Powershell` Console sessions?

Comment: i would start with the call that choco puts in your profile when you install it. that leads to a set of files that seem to load the extensions & funcs as needed.

Comment: can you please point out the location that is in the user profile? I cannot find it. Thanks

Comment: the powershell profiles are located here >>> `$profile | Select-Object -Property *`  <<< the chocolatey stuff is located here >>> `Get-ChildItem -Path env:\choc*` <<< the choco PSM1 file that seems to start the process is here >>> `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chocolatey\tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1` <<<

Comment: Yes, `Import-Module $ChocolateyProfile` did the trick. Can you please add this to question as an answer. So that this question can be closed and other people with same enquiry can benefit when they do their search? Thanks

Comment: done! ... and you are most welcome! glad to have helped ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

when you install chocolatey, it puts a few lines of code in your powershell profile that load the various extensions & functions. [*grin*] you can find the various profiles here ...

```
$Profile |
    Select-Object -Property *
```

you can find the choco files here ...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path env:\choc*
```

for me, the loader is here ...

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chocolatey\tools\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyProfile.psm1
```

the code in my profile that loads it is ...

```
Import-Module $ChocolateyProfile
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533743/497403 did it for me - importing C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1 instead of chocolateyProfile.psm1

Answer (score 4):

There is a Chocolatey Package that seeks to help with this sort of thing as well.  You can find it here:

https://chocolatey.org/packages/chocolateypowershell

Once installed, you can simply double click the icon that is placed on your desktop, and you will have a PowerShell Session that already has the Chocolatey pieces loaded into the session.

This approach can be useful if you only want those pieces loaded at certain times, and not always.

Answer (score 0):

To gain access to the `choco` APIs directly from an existing `PowerShell` terminal session, execute this command:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\chocolateypowershell\tools\chocolateyEnvironment.ps1
```

This is important for me because I debug scripts using `PowerShell ISE` but it would also work in the `Visual Studio Code` Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I have used  `Import-Module C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1`